# Javascript: Keep getting one off when looking for consecutive numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing some coding practice and found some questions online.
I keep getting 1 integer lower than expected when looking to return the number of consecutive numbers inside an array.

```
function LongestConsecutive(arr) { 

  arr.sort((a,b) => {return a-b});

  let highest = 0;
  let counter = 0;
  let prevNum;

  arr.forEach((num,index,arr) => {
      if (prevNum === undefined) {
        prevNum = num   
      } else {

          if (num + 1 == arr[index + 1]) {
              counter += 1;
              highest = Math.max(highest,counter)
          } else {
             counter = 0;
          } 
      }
  })
  return highest;      
}
```

for example, the input [5, 6, 1, 2, 8, 9, 7], should return 5 -- because when sorted, there are 5 consecutive numbers.  I keep getting one lower than I should so for this example, I get 4.  The only way to get the correct answer is when I return 'highest + 1', which obviously is avoiding the problem.

Comment: 1 and 2 are also consecutive numbers. How do you address that? Or is it the question is consecutive numbers with most numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first iteration will hit

```
if (prevNum === undefined) {
  prevNum = num;
}
```

But isn’t that already the first consecutive number? So `counter = 1;` and `highest = 1;` should be here.

Next, you reset `counter = 0;` in an `else` case. Why? There’s at least one number that is consecutive, so reset it to `1` instead.

Then, you’re not really using `prevNum` for anything. `if (prevNum === undefined)` can be replaced by `if (index === 1)`.

You then check if the current number (`num`) precedes the next number (`arr[index + 1]`), but you skip this check for the first index. How about checking if the current number succeeds the previous?

This code uses the above changes plus some code quality changes:

```
function longestConsecutive(arr) { // Non-constructor functions start with a lower-case letter
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b); // Use expression form

  let highest = 0;
  let counter = 0;

  arr.forEach((num, index, arr) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      highest = 1;
      counter = 1;
    } else if (num - 1 === arr[index - 1]) { // Merge `else if`, use strict equal
      counter += 1;
      highest = Math.max(highest, counter);
    } else {
      counter = 1;
    }
  });

  return highest;
}
```

Comment: actually @Xufox, what did you mean by : "arr.sort((a, b) => a - b); // Use expression form "  -- why that way versus the way with return?

Comment: @RaymonOpie It’s shorter and cleaner.

Comment: @RaymonOpie the return is implicit

Answer (score 0):

Well, by the definition of consecutive, you'll always have 1 consecutive number. So you need to start the counter from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be achieved with array:reduce

```js
function longestRun(array) { 
  const { streak } = array
    .sort((a, b) => a - b) // sort into ascending order
    .reduce(({ count, streak }, current, index, arr) => {
      if (current === arr[index - 1] + 1) {
        count++; // increment if 1 more than previous
      } else {
        count = 1; // else reset to 1
      }
      return {count, streak: Math.max(streak, count)};
    }, { count: 0, streak: 0 }); // initial value is 0,0 in case of empty array

  return streak;      
}

console.log(longestRun([])); // 0
console.log(longestRun([0])); // 1
console.log(longestRun([0, 1])); // 2
console.log(longestRun([0, 1, 0])); // 2
console.log(longestRun([0, 0, 0])); // 1
console.log(longestRun([2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0])); // 4
```

Comment: Ah, durp, I totally mis-understood what OP meant by consecutive, also explains the sort, which I was wondering about... fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to split arrays into subarrays via a condition, you can do it by splitting the array at non consecutive points.

```js
const arr = [5, 6, 1, 2, 8, 9, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14]

// utility for splitting array at condition points
const splitBy = (arr, cond) => arr.reduce((a, cur, i, src) => {
  if(cond(cur, i, src)){
    a.push([])
  }
  a[a.length - 1].push(cur)
  return a
}, [])


const consecutives = splitBy(
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b), 
  (cur, i, src) => cur !== src[i-1] + 1
).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
  
// largest consecutive list will be the first array
console.log(consecutives[0].length)
```

Comment: I really like the conciseness, that's awesome, but it doesn't work correctly if a consecutive run happens later in the array.  For example `[5, 6, 1, 2, 8, 9, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14]` should return 5 for `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` but instead returns 4 for `[11, 12, 13, 14]`.

Comment: Ah, sneaky sneaky, took me way too long to realize you snuck another sort in there. :) Kind of loses the conciseness now though.

Comment: Yeah. Tried to find a nice way of splitting an array by a condition. If you have that utility, it can become pretty concise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code (its different than the one posted in the question) which gives the expected result. In addition, if there are two sets of consecutive numbers of same (and largest) length, both are printed,

```
var arr = [5, 6, 1, 2, 8, 9, 7, 99, 98];
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

var prevNum = arr[0];
var consecutiveNumbersArr = [prevNum];

// Map of consecutiveNumbersArr array as key and
// the array length as values
var arrMap = new Map();

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

    let num = arr[i];

    if (num === prevNum+1) {

        prevNum = num;
        consecutiveNumbersArr.push(num);
        continue;
    }

    arrMap.set(consecutiveNumbersArr, consecutiveNumbersArr.length);
    consecutiveNumbersArr = [];
    consecutiveNumbersArr.push(num);
    prevNum = num;
}

arrMap.set(consecutiveNumbersArr, consecutiveNumbersArr.length);

// the largest length of all the consecutive numbers array
var largest = 0; 

for (let value of arrMap.values()) {
    if (value > largest) {
        largest = value;
    }
}

// print the result - the largest consecutive array
for (let [key, value] of arrMap) {
    if (value === largest) {
        console.log("RESULT: " + key);
    }
}
```